# Obtengo otro resultado en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy obteniendo unas coordenadas desde una base de datos y al momento de retornar la informacion me retorna la que he definido al principio en la funcion que es la variable dato, y no en la que añado despues de obtener la informacion mediante Json.

aqui el codigo(explico en comentarios del codigo lo que quiero obtener):

```
function obtenerbus(){
    var dato=new google.maps.LatLng(-17.848616,-63.158049);// ESTA INFORMACION ES LA QUE OBTENGO(NO DESEO OBTENER)

      var ajax=$.ajax({
            data:'',
            url:'consultar.php',
            type:'POST',
            success:function(response){
                var resultados= JSON.parse(response);
                dato=new google.maps.LatLng(resultados[0],resultados[1] );
                alert(dato);//En el alert muestra=-17.821754,-63.175449 ****ESTA INFO DESEO OBTENER****

            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Error al obtener informacion');
            }
        });

        alert(dato);//muestra=-17.848616,-63.158049(NO DESEO OBTENER)
    return dato;
}
```

no se porque no aplica el cambio en:

```
dato=new google.maps.LatLng(resultados[0],resultados[1] );
```

que puede estar mal?
(la informacion la obtengo sin problemas de la base de datos)

Comment: acabo de ponerla afuera de la funcion pero igual me vota ese mismo resultado. es como si no este copiando el nuevo valor obtenido a la variable dato. hago la prueba con el alert y me muestra el valor el primer valor insertado el segundo no quiere insertarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar el método `Object.assign()` que copia sólo las propiedades enumerables y propias del objeto origen a un objeto destino. ya que estas trabajando con instancias de objetos.
el objeto `dato` que es una instancia `new`.y no con variables primitivas como `integer` o `string`.

Aquí el código trabajado, pruebalo espero que sea lo que estas buscando

```
function obtenerbus(){
var dato=new google.maps.LatLng(-17.848616,-63.158049);

  var ajax=$.ajax({
        data:'',
        url:'consultar.php',
        type:'POST',
        success:function(response){
            var resultados= JSON.parse(response);

            var dato1=new google.maps.LatLng(resultados[0],resultados[1]);
                dato=Object.assign(dato, dato1);

        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error al obtener informacion');
        }
    });


 return dato;
}
```

(*saque los alert para hacerlo mas legible el código*)

Comment: Estupendo, me funciona gracias.